# First sibling div treated as a background of second dynamic div

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML Markup,

```
    <div class="bluredBackground"></div>
    <div class="content">
       Hi This is dynamic content.<br>
       If the div height increases then first div height <br>
       should be automatically increase.
    </div>
```

I want first div height should automatically increase whenever the second div height increases because of its dynamic content.

As of now, I was able to place one div on top of another,

```
.content {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    border:1px solid;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:10;
    background-color: white;
}

.bluredBackground {
    width:70%;
    height:70%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:0;
    border:1px solid;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}
```

How can I solve this problem with CSS?
I was trying this thing > http://jsfiddle.net/hsinghbisht/nLj5dqay/2/

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to question, but what exactly are you planning with the 2nd div (blurred) being on the same height as 1st one?

If you want the fancy red blurred glare behind, then just use `box-shadow`. Add it to the `.content` and it will work pretty identical

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px red;
```

However, if you definitely need to use the red blurred div, then you cannot solve that with plain CSS. You must use JavaScript and look for class style of one element and copy it to the next one.

Example:

```
window.onload = () => 
{
  const div1 = document.querySelector('.bluredBackground');
  const div2 = document.querySelector('.content');

  div1.style.height = `${div2.offsetHeight}px`;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to use the first div as a blurred background and the second dynamic div is in the foreground. I want to avoid js for this case, in the worst case, I will go with it.

Comment: I had an assumption you only wanted 2nd div for red blur on the borders, but in that case, just use the JS snippet I wrote above and execute it at your discretion (whether it be by window.onload or a function call or whatever). If it helped you, don't forget to mark answer.